# Adding slices of a dataframe to another dataframe in a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes. One is empty and the other one contains a lot of rows. I want to group the dataframe with values and then slice the first 3 rows of each group and add them to the empty dataframe. I want each new 3 rows to be put into a new column.

I have tried, concat, join, append.. but I cannot figure out how to...

My code so far:

```
df = pd.Dataframe()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30],
                   'D': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

df_dictionary = df2.groupby("C")

for key, df_values in df_dictionary:
    df_values = df_values.head(3)
    df = pd.concat(df, df_values["D"], axis=1)
    print(df)
```

The results would look like this of the empty dataframe:

```
index   col 1   col 2   col 3
0   1   5   8
1   2   6   9
2   3   7   10
```

I want to add the first 3 values in the D column for every group to the empty dataframe and put them in a new column every time.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using `cumcount` before `pivot`

```
n=3 
df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('C').cumcount()).pivot(index='key',columns='C',values='D').iloc[:n,:]
Out[730]: 
C     10   20    30
key                
0    5.0  1.0   8.0
1    6.0  2.0   9.0
2    7.0  3.0  10.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 2):

This answer has one requirement: ***each group must have at least `n` values per group***.

Using `head` + `reshape`

---

```
n = 3
u = df2.groupby('C').head(n)['D'].values

pd.DataFrame(u.reshape(-1, n, order='F'), columns=[f'col {i+1}' for i in range(n)])
```

```
   col 1  col 2  col 3
0      1      5      8
1      2      6      9
2      3      7     10
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution utilizes the dictionary returns by `groupby.groups` to construct new dataframe

```
gb = df2.set_index('D').groupby('C')
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gb.groups, orient='index').iloc[:,:3].T

Out[2033]:
   10  20  30
0   5   1   8
1   6   2   9
2   7   3  10
```

Or using `head` after `T`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gb.groups, orient='index').T.head(3)

Out[2034]:
    10   20    30
0  5.0  1.0   8.0
1  6.0  2.0   9.0
2  7.0  3.0  10.0
```